# installing ns2 in ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, ns2

when I give this command

```
apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake libxmu-dev
```

it gives the following error

```
E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'autoconf' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'automake' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libxmu-dev
```

Comment: Include in your question the output of these four commands: 1)  `lsb_release -sr`, 2) `sudo apt-get update`, 3) `apt-cache policy build-essential`, 4) `grep -r ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list*`. Please [edit] your question to do so and please use proper formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Try to first enable the main repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main"
sudo apt-get update
```

And finally:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake libxmu-dev
```

Comment: -1. Just to install `build-essential` and GNU autotools you really don't need to enable all these repositories.

Comment: thank  you sir a bundle of thanx for your kind information

Comment: @gertvdijk: Thanks, I've updated my answer as all those packages seem to be in main

Comment: it works fine now

Comment: Shouldn't the main repository be enabled by default?